# command line - create shortcut to a exe file on the desktop

Tags: command-line

i need to create shortcuts to many exe files on my desktop.

i used this command line: mklink /d Name c:\folder\subfolder\action.exe

it created a folder instead of an exe shortcut.

Plse advise how to do this. thks

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\System32>mklink Creates a symbolic link.

> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

```
/D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
        symbolic link.
/H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
/J      Creates a Directory Junction.
Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
        refers to.
```